# How to eagerly load nested entities in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have these models:

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<CategoryProduct> Products {get; set;}
}

public class CategoryProduct
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int CategoryId {get; set;}
    public int ProductId {get; set;}
    public virtual Category Category {get; set;}
    public virtual Product Product {get; set;}
}

public class Product
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

I'm loading a `Category` object and related `Products` by doing the following in the service layer:

```
categoryRepository.Get(x => x.Id == categoryId, x => x.Products);
```

And the corresponding generic repository method:

```
public virtual IQueryable<T> Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] include)
{
    var set = include.Aggregate<Expression<Func<T, object>>, IQueryable<T>>
                (dbSet, (current, expression) => current.Include(expression));

    return set.Where(predicate).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

To a certain extent, the above works fine because I can load one `Cateory` and corresponding `Products` with one SQL statement. However the `Product` property each `CategoryProduct` object is `null`.

How can I tell `EF` to also load each `Product` related to the `CategoryProduct`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by doing:

```
categoryRepository.Get(x => x.Id == categoryId, 
                       x => x.Products.Select(p => p.Product));
```

This [EF blog post](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232) helped a lot!